# How to describe three alternating options in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to describe three alternative options in one sentence. Lets say the below sentence:

"By tuning its parameter, the network can become either A-centric or B-centric or even it can maintain a balance between the two."

or,

"The network is capable of becoming either A-centric or B-centric or it can even maintain a balance between the two by tuning its parameter."

How to write this sentence properly? Thanks.

Comment: "The network can be tuned to be A-centric or B-centric or to maintain a balance between A and B."

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

"even" adds emphasis, and suggests that this example is in some way unexpected.

If you say "it can even", even is modifying "can", so you're saying that "it **can** do X, despite you thinking that it **can not** do X".  This is the meaning you're after:  you're saying "in addition to doing the individual things, it can maintain a balance between them, which you might not have expected"

However, if you say "even it can" you're modifying "it" - suggesting that you might have thought that **other things can do X, but not this thing**.

It's like saying "Even elephants can jump, but just a tiny distance".   "even" is acting on "elephants" here. Ie, "you thought that elephants cannot jump, but they actually can, and I'm implying that lots more, perhaps all, animals can jump to some extent."

That's not what you're trying to say here.  Saying "even it can maintain a balance between the two." suggests that **all** networks can maintain a balance, even this one, implying that people would have expected the network to **not** be as good as balancing the two things as other networks are.  That's almost the opposite of the point you're trying to make.